# How to fix content in expanding div (jsFiddle included)

Tags: jquery, css-transforms, skew

I'm really close to getting this to work, but I'm a little stuck.

I need the second text to stay put, while the div that contains it expands width-wise. So that the two pieces of text are overlapping each other at all times.

http://jsfiddle.net/29W6R/

**HTML:**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class="page content1">
        <div class='skewfix'>
            <div class='skew'>
                something else in here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page content2">
        <div class='skewfix'>
            <div class='skew'>
                something else in here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.page{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -25%;
    width: 125%;
    transition: width 2s;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: skew(45deg,0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

.skewfix{
    -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg,0);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
}

div.content1{
    background:tomato;
}
div.content2{
    background: blue;
    width:0px;
}

.skew{
    margin:0 0 0 25%;
}

div.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.content1').click(function(){
    $('.content2').width("125%");
});

$('.content2').click(function(){
    $('.content2').width("0%");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your CSS

```
.skew {margin: 0 0 0 220px;width:140px;}
```

Your both text will remain at same place when your div expand/collapse

Comment: This a huge step forward! I knew I was missing something simple. Now I need to make it so that it displays properly on window resize, but that should just be a matter of adjusting margins now. Thanks!